# Beginner questions on deployment and migrations

Tags: symfony, web-deployment, database-migration

I'm working on a Symfony 2-application and I use Doctrine migrations to create the database. Now it is time to deploy my application to the production server, and I need some guidance on how to manage migrations. First, how can I get console access to my live server to run the migration command? If I can´t run migrations, can I import my local database to the new server, or will this break the application´s mapping structure, so it won´t work? I´m sorry if this seems like a silly question, but I really can´t find much information about this. I have searched for it a lot.

Comment: getting console access to server in better words is called connecting the server via SSH so that you can execute commands.Goggle searching the same will help you solving the first part of your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several options:

1. A terminal connection to your deployment server to run the app/console there
2. Execute the migration in your local terminal, with env=prod, and with a parameters.yml file that points to your prod database
3. Export data from your local database, and import it in your remote one

Take care when doing these, and make proper backups to avoid data losses

Comment: i have ssh into my ubuntu server and now i want to run the migrations. But when i do php app/console doctrine:migrations:migrate Class 'Sensio\Bundle\GeneratorBundle\SensioGeneratorBundle' not found ..

Comment: You need to update the vendor libraries as well: composer update